# Multi-Line text is not clearly visible on UILabel

Tags: ios, autolayout

Actually am calculating the tablviewCell.Height based on the content. So i am using **SystemLayoutFittingSize** Api. Because i need to support iOS7.0. And even i tried with UIAutomaticDimension its working fine for >8.0[image: In this Screenshot the brownColor Label is content is not fully Visible]

Actually the PriceLabel is first Priority for me. Based on the PriceLabel content. the BrownLabel content should  automatically adjust. For this i have used *ContentCompressionResistancePriority.Horizontal=1000* for the PriceLabel and width(51@999). **The middle one is adjusting fine.** but the Content is not clearly visible. For BrownLabel: PreferredWidth=203 and Height>=31 i given.

*The following code for UITableviewCellHeight Calculation:*

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

`// Calculate a height based on a cell
if(!self.customCell) {
    self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell
NSDictionary *sourceDictionary = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
[self.customCell feedInfo:sourceDictionary];

// Get the height for the cell
CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

// Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;
NSLog(@"Height: %f",height+separatorHeight);
return height + separatorHeight;}`